# Enquiry about joining 2 DataSets into a single Report

Tags: c#, windows, forms, reportviewer

I'm currently facing a problem whereby I could only bind 1 dataset with 1 report.rdlc. I have 2 data tables inside a dataset. Is there any ways that I could show the 2 data tables inside a single report?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no option to do that using Crystal Reports. However, there are 2 possible ways to work around this :-

1. Create a custom datatable for this report that combines the fields you need from each datatable and bind this new datatable to this report
2. Create a subreport embedded within the report and bind the 2nd datatable to that subreport instead.

   ```
       report.SetDataSource(new[] { debitCreditMain });
       report.Subreports["details"].SetDataSource(debitCreditMain.DetailList);
   ```

Comment: Any examples of how to bind the 2nd datatable to the subreport because I have tried the way but it seems not to work though.

Comment: I have put in an example of how you can bind a report and a sub-report via code to the corresponding objects. In my example, the main report is bound to a debitCreditMain object and the subreport called Details - is bound to debitCreditMain.DetailList - which is a collection of a different type. I use POCO's but the basic concept is the same and you can replace the same with your 2 corresponding datatables instead